# Crystal Reports vs SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to make a website. According to the requirements I have many simple as well as complex reports which may have more column to display sometimes. I haven't worked with the reporting in web. I want to know which is best from both of them according to my requirement.

Comment: Sorry for doing this, but i would actually say neither and instead offer up a third option: [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports)

Comment: ohh how its better than the two i mentioned ?

Comment: Unlike other reporting tools, you can render pure HTML.  Crystal requires the user to install a plug in.  That in itself can become a challenge on older browsers or if the computer is managed by an overly aggressive administrator.  And unlike the other two, it is free... As in beer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually **knowing** your requirements - my gut feeling would be to favor **SQL Server Reporting Services**.

Why?

- It comes with SQL Server, so it's basically *free* (if you have SQL Server anyway)
- it's quite capable in terms of rendering and exporting
- it's also extensible with .NET code, if you ever need to
- you can schedule reports at a given time etc.

Crystal Reports on the other hand

- is a separate add-on you have to buy (and it's quite expensive, too)
- it's a bit clunky and hard to use at times (in my opinion)
- it doesn't integrate nearly as well with SQL Server and ASP.NET

Comment: i think crystal reports is free, if you have visual studio. Crystal reports is better for some very complex reports. but in general- Reporting Services is way more fun and more easy to use.

Comment: @Jānis: that's a **very limited** Crystal Reports version - no server components (i.e. no scheduling of reports), very limited connectitivity ....

Comment: @marc_s i gone through to SQL server reporting with the help of some step by step guide. there i was guided that sql reports once build they supposed to be deployed on reporting server but what i should do in learning environment at home.where do i deploy it and use it in my asp.net web ? please suggest me something.thanks